# SQL: Full outer join or Union or neither?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an A_to_C table which is many-to-many join table between A and C

```
╔═══════╦══════════╗
║ a_col ║  c_col   ║
╠═══════╬══════════╣
║ a     ║ x        ║
║ b     ║ y        ║
║ c     ║ z        ║
╚═══════╩══════════╝
```

I also have a B_to_C table which is many-to-many join table from B and C

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ b_col ║ c_col ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ g     ║ u     ║
║ h     ║ v     ║
║ i     ║ w     ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

I want to achieve a result like this:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ a_col ║ c_col ║ b_col ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ a     ║ x     ║ NULL  ║
║ b     ║ y     ║ NULL  ║
║ c     ║ z     ║ NULL  ║
║ NULL  ║ u     ║ g     ║
║ NULL  ║ v     ║ h     ║
║ NULL  ║ w     ║ i     ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

I have no idea if I can use joins because x, y, z values in A_to_C cannot be matched with u, v, w values in B_to_C

I can't use unions because I need separate a_col and b_col columns or can I?

I might not be aware of a SQL construct that can achieve the desired result though.

As a bonus, I wanna transform the columns in the results as:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ a_col ║ c_col ║ b_col  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ true  ║ x     ║ false  ║
║ true  ║ y     ║ false  ║
║ true  ║ z     ║ false  ║
║ false ║ u     ║ true   ║
║ false ║ v     ║ true   ║
║ false ║ w     ║ true   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

TIA!

Comment: UNION ALL. Select null for the separate a_col and b_col columns,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL:

```
select a_col, c_col, null b_col
from A_to_C
union all
select null, c_col, b_col
from B_to_C
```

and for the other query:

```
select 
  (t.a_col is not null) a_col, 
  t.c_col, 
  (t.b_col is not null) b_col
from (
  select a_col, c_col, null b_col
  from A_to_C
  union all
  select null, c_col, b_col
  from B_to_C
) t
```

Or set the boolean values directly in th eunioned queries:

```
select true a_col, c_col, false b_col
from A_to_C
union all
select false a_col, c_col, true b_col
from B_to_C
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=798597ae463f724fa3f412eea34b0058).
Results:

```
> a_col | c_col | b_col
> :---- | :---- | :----
> a     | x     | null 
> b     | y     | null 
> c     | z     | null 
> null  | u     | g    
> null  | v     | h    
> null  | w     | i
```

and

```
> a_col | c_col | b_col
> :---- | :---- | :----
> t     | x     | f    
> t     | y     | f    
> t     | z     | f    
> f     | u     | t    
> f     | v     | t    
> f     | w     | t
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick one @forpas , I wasn't aware of UNION ALL! Can you suggest how I can achieve the transformed result as well?

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! Though I'm accepting the other answer because I don't want duplicates if a c_col value is present in both the tables, yours looks very clean though.

Comment: What duplicates? You can't have duplicates.

Comment: If there is a case of whole rows being duplicates you can use UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: I mean if there is a row in A_to_C like  |  a | x | and a row in B_to_C like | b | x | then there would be two rows right @forpas?

Comment: I'm accepting your answer anyway cuz my question was framed in such a way that there won't be duplicates between a_col and b_col

Comment: Isn't this the requirement? All the rows of both tables? Also | a | x |  and | b | x | are 2 different rows. If the final results contain full duplicate rows, as I mentioned earlier, use UNION which removes duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s for this.

```sql
SELECT a.a_col, c.c_col, b.b_col
FROM C c
LEFT OUTER JOIN A_to_C a ON c.c_col = a.c_col
LEFT OUTER JOIN B_to_C b ON c.c_col = b.c_col
WHERE a.a_col IS NOT NULL OR b.b_col IS NOT NULL;
```

The `WHERE` clause is optional if you can guarantee that all values in `c` have a corresponding value in `a` or `b` or both.

For the bonus query, change the `SELECT` to

```sql
SELECT a.a_col IS NOT NULL AS a_col,
    c.c_col,
    b.b_col IS NOT NULL AS b_col
```

Here's the [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4AaCDwbziy8QWNnuzNif5a/1).

Btw, depending on what your use-case is, if a value in `c` can be in BOTH `a` and `b`, using `JOIN`s will give you a single row for that value of `c`, while using `UNION ALL` will give you two rows, one with `NULL` in `a` and one with `NULL` in `b`.  I don't know which is more performant for large tables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @dx_over_dt . Your first query gave me empty rows, when I removed the last where clause from the query my a_col and b_col are all NULLs. If you can whip up a demo like the accepted answer did, I can +1 this

Comment: Yeah, I threw it into db-fiddle.com and realized my mistake.  I'm fixing it now.

Comment: @socket_var updated.  My mistake was joining `c.c_col = a.a_col` rather than `= a.c_col`.

Comment: @socket_var Also you should consider my *btw* paragraph.  I don't think `UNION ALL` is what you want in most common cases.

Comment: That's an excellent point @dx_over_dt . Though I accepted the other answer because my question didn't explicitly say there would be duplicates