# Join 2 many-to-many tables and get 3 adjacent boolean columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

Let's say there are three tables `A`, `B` and `C` where

Table A is:

```
╔═══════╗
║ col_1 ║
╠═══════╣
║ a     ║
║ b     ║
║ c     ║
╚═══════╝
```

Table B is:

```
╔═══════╗
║ col_2 ║
╠═══════╣
║ o     ║
║ p     ║
║ q     ║
╚═══════╝
```

Table C is:

```
╔═══════╗
║ c_col ║
╠═══════╣
║ x     ║
║ y     ║
║ z     ║
╚═══════╝
```

Let's say there is a many-to-many relationship between table A and table C via a mapping table `A_to_C` shown below:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ col_1 ║ c_col ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ a     ║ x     ║
║ a     ║ y     ║
║ b     ║ y     ║
║ b     ║ z     ║
║ c     ║ x     ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

Also there is a many-to-many relationship between table B and table C via a mapping table `B_to_C` shown below:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ col_2 ║ c_col ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ o     ║ y     ║
║ o     ║ z     ║
║ p     ║ x     ║
║ q     ║ x     ║
║ q     ║ y     ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

For value `'b'` in `col_1` and value `'q'` in `col_2` I need to get the result as:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ c_col ║ col_1 ║ col_2  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ x     ║ NULL  ║ q      ║
║ y     ║ b     ║ q      ║
║ z     ║ b     ║ NULL   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

which can later be transformed into:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ c_col ║ col_1 ║ col_2 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ x     ║ False ║ True  ║
║ y     ║ True  ║ True  ║
║ z     ║ True  ║ False ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147861/sql-full-outer-join-or-union-or-neither) but in this case
due to many to many relationships with duplicate column values I am not able to achieve the above result without duplicate columns using the solution in the above link.

Comment: Questions should be rather self contained - if the referenced question is edited or removed, this one won't make any sense

Comment: Sorry @Andronicus , added more explanation and fixed the errors. This question was very hard to form, hope it makes sense now! Btw I only edited this question, didn;t edit/remove the link, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate this result with a series of `LEFT JOIN`s, placing your `col_1` and `col_2` filters in the `JOIN` conditions:

```
SELECT C.c_col, ac.col_1, bc.col_2
FROM C
LEFT JOIN A_to_C ac ON ac.c_col = C.c_col AND ac.col_1 = 'b'
LEFT JOIN B_to_C bc ON bc.c_col = C.c_col AND bc.col_2 = 'q'
```

Output:

```
c_col   col_1   col_2
x       (null)  q
y       b       q
z       b       (null)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31319/6)

Those values can then be converted into booleans by testing they are not `NULL`:

```
SELECT C.c_col, ac.col_1 IS NOT NULL AS col_1, bc.col_2 IS NOT NULL AS col_2
FROM C
LEFT JOIN A_to_C ac ON ac.c_col = C.c_col AND ac.col_1 = 'b'
LEFT JOIN B_to_C bc ON bc.c_col = C.c_col AND bc.col_2 = 'q'
```

Output:

```
c_col   col_1   col_2
x       false   true
y       true    true
z       true    false
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31319/12)

Comment: Is there a need to perform 4 joins? Joining tables are covering in this example

Comment: @Andronicus no of course not. I've removed the superfluous ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
select c.c_col, ac.col_1 is not null, bc.col_2 is not null
from C c
left join (select * from A_to_C where col_1 = 'b') ac on c.c_col = ac.c_col
left join (select * from B_to_C where col_2 = 'b') bc on c.c_col = bc.c_col
where (ac.col_1, bc.col2) = ('b', 'q')
```

Comment: @Nick you're right, that was a stupid mistake, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the two LEFT JOINS and the IS NOT NULL; `EXISTS()` already yields a boolean:

---

```
SELECT C.c_col
        , EXISTS( SELECT *
                FROM A_to_C ac
                WHERE ac.c_col = C.c_col AND ac.col_1 = 'b'
                ) AS col_1
        , EXISTS( SELECT *
                FROM B_to_C bc
                WHERE bc.c_col = C.c_col AND bc.col_2 = 'q'
                ) AS col_2
FROM C
        ;
```

Comment: And I think this would be the most efficient solution